# ¿Como convertir un array de pares [clave,valor] en un objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, object

Tengo un array que previamente ordene

```
'Array: [ [ '2015', [ 11, 12 ] ],
  [ '2016', [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] ],
  [ '2017', [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] ] ]'

'Array reverseado:  [ [ '2017', [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] ],
  [ '2016', [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] ],
  [ '2015', [ 11, 12 ] ] ]'
```

Ahora ese array reverseado lo quiero (por cuestiones de mi algoritmo), convertir en un objeto

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código que has intentado para ver donde esta el error y un ejemplo del resultado esperado?

Comment: Falta indicar los buscado/investigado como se indica en [ask].

Comment: Como se debería interpretar en la conversión esto `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]`  como valor unico o como objeto interno asi `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] ->  { '1': [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]}` y aplicar recursivamente??

Answer (score 0):

Tengo hecha una función que pasa de Array a Objeto. Espero te sirva:

```js
function aObjeto(array) {
    var objeto = {};
    for (var i in array) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            objeto[i] = aObjeto(array[i]);
        } else {
            objeto[i] = array[i];
        }
    }

    return objeto;
}

var array = [];
array["Miembro1"] = "Valor Miembro 1";
array["Miembro2"] = [];
array["Miembro2"]["Miembro21"] = "Valor Miembro 2.1";
array["Miembro2"]["Miembro22"] = [];
array["Miembro2"]["Miembro22"]["Miembro221"] = "Valor Miembro 2.2.1";

//Verdadero
console.log(Array.isArray(array));

var objeto = aObjeto(array);
//Falso
console.log(Array.isArray(objeto));
console.log(objeto);
```

Comment: El problema es que tu función sirve para arreglos de una dimensión, mientras que el del OP es de dos dimensiones, haría falta otro ciclo para recorrer cada subarreglo.

Comment: Ahí lo edité para que funcione recursivamente.